# Организация приема и перевода платежей на сайте рекламной биржи

Tags: платежи, ecommerce

Сейчас в разработке рекламная биржа, где рекламодатели будут покупать услуги блогеров по публикации рекламных постов в vk, instagram, twitter и т.д.

Вопрос в том, как оптимальным образом организовать взаиморасчеты исполнителей с заказчиками и получить при этом минимальную комиссию. Работать будем через юридическое лицо (ООО) по упрощенной схеме налогообложения (6% с оборота).

Пока на ум пришла только такая схема формирования итоговой комиссии сервиса:

1. Платежи принимаются через PayKeeper и Яндекс.Кассу (комиссия 2-5% в зависимости от типа платежа)
2. Далее средства поступают на расчетный счет организации и с них платится налог 6% (вариант с 15% от прибыли здесь подходит не лучшим образом, т.к. будет множество микроплатежей).
3. Далее средства необходимо перевести исполнителям (планирую пока вывод средств 1 или 2 раза в неделю).

Вот здесь вопрос к знающим людям. Как вы выплачиваете средства исполнителям со счета организации? Как все это оформляется юридически и через бухгалтерию? Есть ли какие сервисы, которые готовы организовать этот этап работы на аутсорсе?